# Can't create a range in Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, xcode8, ios10

I am trying to make a range in Swift 3 that I already had in Swift 2 but it keeps giving me this error: 
`String may not be indexed with 'Int', it has variable size elements`

Here is my code:

```
let range = expireRange!.startIndex.advancedBy(n: 7) ..< expireRange!.startIndex.advancedBy(n: 16)
```

expiredRange is a `Range<Index>?`

In Swift 2, I had:

```
let range = expireRange!.startIndex.advancedBy(7)...expireRange!.startIndex.advancedBy(16)
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In Swift 3, "Collections move their index", see
 [A New Model for Collections and Indices](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0065-collections-move-indices.md) on Swift evolution.

Here is an example for String ranges and indices:

```
let string = "ABCDEFG"
if let range = string.range(of: "CDEF") {
    let lo = string.index(range.lowerBound, offsetBy: 1)
    let hi = string.index(range.lowerBound, offsetBy: 3)
    let subRange = lo ..< hi
    print(string[subRange]) // "DE"
}
```

The

```
public func index(_ i: Index, offsetBy n: IndexDistance) -> Index
```

method is called on the string to calculate the new indices from the
range (which has properties `lower/upperBound` now instead of
`start/endIndex`).