# Migration from swift2 to swift3 and changes for advanceBy for Range<String.Index>

Tags: swift3

There is a  function

```
func find(... rangeString1: Range<String.Index>, ...) ...
```

and this function has in swift2

```
while i >= minimalIdentity{

var first = rangeString1.startIndex
var last = first.advancedBy(i, limit: rangeString1.endIndex)
...
```

Question is how should look the

```
var last
```

in swift3

```
var first = rangeString1.lowerBound
var last =
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38070273/cant-create-a-range-in-swift-3.

Comment: @Martin R Thanks. Is there swift 2 analog of last for range  in swift3. I see only upperBound, but it is analog of endIndex in swift2 ?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in that answer, start/endIndex have been renamed to lower/upperBound.

Comment: @Martin R Sorry, I mean -  let last = range!.last which gives index lower on 1 unit than -  let end = range!.endIndex.

Comment: Swift 3 has `Range` and `CountableRange`. The latter is a collection and has a `last` property.

Comment: @Martin R If I am trying initialise range as CountableRange<String.Index> (instead of Range<String.Index> in swift2) compiler is complaining that index is not confirm to protocol Strideable

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work with a string index.

Comment: @Martin R So, I have problem not only with .last for range for string (I can use indirect way with offsetBy, aka advanceBy to get the last value). But, I also cannot get count from range, and I don't have idea how to get it. Do you have an idea how to get count from range?

Comment: Here is another example for Swift 3: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38228514/1187415. In Swift 3 you always need the original collection to perform calculations with its indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever string those indices belong to is responsible for this in Swift 3:

```
let first = rangeString1.lowerBound
let last = myString.index(first, offsetBy: i, limit: rangeString1.upperBound)
```

Comment: I cannot use rangeString1.index, compiler is saying that Range<Index> has no member index

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought that was your string. You basically need to call it on the string that the indices belong to, see my edit.

Comment: If I need string that is bad feature of swift3 in comparison with swift2. So, I have to make substring for Range<Index> and then can use it, while in swift2 I could use directly the Range<Index>.

Comment: Yeah, you'll need the string that the indices belong to.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`endIndex`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1539571-endindex):

```
var last = rangeString1.endIndex
```

Comment: I cannot, I need advanceBy for iteration in while loop

Comment: Ah okay, well in that case I see someone already mentioned [`index(_:offsetBy:limit:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/indexpath/1780097-index)